# Vectorization properties proof

Tags: linear-algebra

On wikipedia I find the following property for the vectorization. If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times l}$ then

$$
vec(AB) = (I_l \otimes A) vec(B) = (B^T \otimes I_m) vec(A)
$$

I can easily show that $vec(AB) = (I_l \otimes A) vec(B)$ Indeed

$$
vec(AB) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
ABe_1 \\
ABe_2 \\
\vdots \\
ABe_n
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
A & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & A & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & A
\end{array}
\right) vec(B) =
\left( I_n \otimes A \right) vec(B)
$$

However I don't know how to to prove the other identity. I suspect is something similar to the procedure I followed but I just cannot see it.

Can you help?

Comment: In general, we have $\operatorname{vec}(MAN)=(N^T\otimes M)\operatorname{vec}(A)$. Since both sides are bilinear in $(M,N)$, it suffices to prove the identity when $M=E_{ij}$ and $N=E_{kl}$, where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix whose only nonzero element is a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more straightforward (like the calculation I have above) than going through a basis.

Comment: Also I just tried with the basis. I just get confused with the calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove it for the case when $l = 1$ i.e. $B$ is a single column. Concretely let $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$. Then
$$
(b^T \otimes I_m)\text{vec}(A) = \big(b_1I_m \ \cdots \ b_nI_m\big)\begin{pmatrix} &Ae_1 \\ &\vdots \\ &Ae_n \end{pmatrix} = b_1Ae_1 + \cdots + b_n Ae_n = Ab
$$ Now consider the general case $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times l}$ by noting that each $Be_j = B_{\bullet j}$ is a column:
$$
\text{vec}(AB) = \begin{pmatrix} &AB_{\bullet 1} \\ &\vdots \\ &AB_{\bullet l} \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} &(B_{\bullet 1}^T \otimes I_m)\text{vec}(A) \\ &\vdots \\ &(B_{\bullet l}^T \otimes I_m)\text{vec}(A) \end{pmatrix} = (B^T \otimes I_m)\text{vec}(A)
$$

Comment: In your very last equality, why can you factor $\text{vec}(A)$ out (from the right)? Is it just a straight calculation?

Comment: @user8469759 That is a general property of block matrix multiplication $\begin{pmatrix} &x_1^Ty \\ &\vdots \\ &x_n^T y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} &x_1^T \\ &\vdots \\ &x_n^T \end{pmatrix} y$

Comment: Thank you. The answer was quick and clear.

Answer (score 1):

For any $p\times q$ matrix $X$, we use the superscripted expression $X^{p\times q}$ to stress its size when needed.

In general, we have $\operatorname{vec}(MAN)=(N^T\otimes M)\operatorname{vec}(A)$. Since both sides are bilinear in $(M,N)$, it suffices to prove this identity when $M=E_{ij}^{m_1\times m_2}$ and $N=E_{kl}^{n_1\times n_2}$, where $E_{ij} ^{m_1\times m_2} $ denotes the $m_1\times m_2$ matrix whose only nonzero element is a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position.

For convenience, let us use $0$-based indexing instead of $1$-based indexing. To prove the identity, let $\{e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_{m_1n_2-1}\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{m_1n_2}$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left((E_{kl}^{n_1\times n_2})^T\otimes E_{ij}^{m_1\times m_2}\right)\operatorname{vec}(A^{m_2\times n_1})
&=(E_{lk}^{n_2\times n_1}\otimes E_{ij}^{m_1\times m_2})\operatorname{vec}(A^{m_2\times n_1})\\
&=E_{lm_1+i,\,km_2+j}^{n_2m_1\times n_1m_2}\operatorname{vec}(A^{m_2\times n_1})\\
&=\left(\operatorname{vec}(A^{m_2\times n_1})\right)_{km_2+j}\ e_{lm_1+i}\\
&=a_{jk}e_{lm_1+i}\\
&=\operatorname{vec}(a_{jk}E_{il}^{m_1\times n_2})\\
&= \operatorname{vec}(E_{ij}^{m_1\times m_2}A^{m_2\times n_1}E_{kl}^{n_1\times n_2}).
\end{aligned}
$$